# Laravel: Update .env file by publishing a third-party package

Tags: php, laravel, package, publish, phpdotenv

I have a library which I want to wrap into Laravel package.

My library uses two configs: the public `config.php` for some nonsensitive settings and `.env` private config for sensitive credentials.

I'd like to `vendor:publish` my configs for end user. And it seems fine for public `config.php` but how to publish my `.env` in Laravel-friendly way? I failed to find any way to do it by `vendor:publish`.

Comment: You shouldn't do that. Ask the package users to add info to `.env` file.

Comment: What @AlexeyMezenin said

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin so, no way to do it automatically? Just wanted to make things easier for users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application's `.env` file is primarily there for keeping sensitive information out of configuration files and other resources that often get committed to source control. It's not intended to be published in any way.

What you can do is create a separate configuration file with some sensible defaults preset, while at the same time allowing the user to override them. For example:

```
// my-config.php
return [
    'user_model => env('MY_USER_MODEL', App\User::class),
    ...
];
```

If needed, they can implement their own User model or omit setting it within their own env file and defaulting to the implementation you've specified.

You'll see this approach quite often in packages providing roles, permissions, tenancy, etc.